# Making a LaTex looking justified text in libre office

Tags: plugins, openoffice.org, openoffice-writer, libreoffice, justify

I'm writing at my thesis at the moment.
I'm using Libre Office instead of LaTex - stupid me, i know!
But at this time there is no way to change to LaTex, so i have to deal with it...

I want to make the whole text justified...
But if I do it with the justified button in the Libre Office Writer, it looks really ugly.

In LaTex it seems there is a better *algorithm* to do this...
If there are only 5 words in a line, it looks now like this

```
and                  this                 is               not             good
```

I know, that this happens only, if it's a linebreak. If i use a new paragraph it works perfect! But if I just press SHIFT + ENTER for writing in next line, i have this bad looking text...

But I want to have it looking nice and smooth.

Is there a way to do it better with Libre Office? Any Plugins?
The Version I'm using at the moment is: *LibreOffice 3.4.4 OOO340m1 (Build:402)*

Or do i just have to avoid single line breaks without a paragraph?

(i hope this is correct here in stack overflow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set this in:  `Tools - Options - LibreOffice Writer - Compatibility`

As per libreoffices [documentation](http://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Compatibility#Expand_word_space_on_lines_with_manual_line_breaks_in_justified_paragraphs):

> **Expand word space on lines with manual line breaks in justified paragraphs**
>
> If enabled, Writer adds spacing between words, in lines that end with Shift+Enter in justified paragraphs. If disabled, spacing between words will not be expanded to justify the lines.
> This setting is on by default for .odt text documents. It will be saved and loaded with the document in the .odt text document format. This setting cannot be saved in old .sxw text documents, so this setting is off for .sxw text documents.